# why the answer is always 0 in this c programming code for the question maximun borders from practice problems of hackerearth

Tags: c

You are given a table with n rows and m columns. Each cell is colored with white or black. Considering the shapes created by black cells, what is the maximum border of these shapes?

A shape is a set of connected cells. Two cells are connected if they share an edge. Note that no shape has a hole in it.

Input format

The first line contains t denoting the number of test cases.
The first line of each test case contains n,m integers  denoting the number of rows and columns of the matrix. Here, '#' represents a black cell and '.' represents a white cell.
Each of the next  n lines contains m  integers.
Output format

Print the maximum border of the shapes.
my code is below.

````
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{

    int t,n,m,i,j,max,l,c;

    scanf("%d",&t);

  for(l=0;l<t;l++)

{
  

scanf("%d%d",&n,&m);

    char a[n][m];
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)

    {

        for(j=0;j<m;j++)

        {
scanf("%c",a[n][m]);
        }
    }
}
 for(l=0;l<t;l++)

{
   char a[n][m];
    max=0;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)

    {
c=0;
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)

        {

        if(a[i][j]=='#')

         c++;

        }

     if(c>=max){

    max=c;}

    }

    
    printf("%d\n",max);


    }

}```
````

Comment: The *second* `char a[n][m];` has not been initialised, so it contains indeterminate values. It's unclear to me why you have two loops iterating the number of test cases. Aside: please don't use single-letter variables, *particularly* `l` (or was that a `1`?)

Comment: it is not 1,it is 'l'.2 test cases are;1 is to input the values and other is to check the cases till number of test cases 't'.

Comment: I think you missed my point: instead of having to *explain* that l is ELL not ONE, just don't use it. Then you will write clearer code and people won't get distracted by asking questions they should not have to ask.

Comment: ok,intializing 2 times char a[n][m];was that the problem?

Comment: It is a different array, and there was no point having two loops. This `if(a[i][j]=='#')` is *undefined behaviour* because the second array `char a[n][m];` has not been initialised. Note, you don't learn coding on these challenge sites: they are places to have a bit of fun, once you do know how to code.